# How to hide a cardview from a Recyclerview

Tags: android

I've 2 cardviews in layout, the layout I display is a part of a Recyclerview, which is reated multiple times.

**I want to display 2nd cardview only in specific situations; But it leaves empty spaces instead when I don't want to display it.**

I'm using `android:visibility="invisible"` for 2nd cardview by default

My 2nd cardview code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

...

  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:visibility="invisible">

...
```

[image]

Comment: if you don't want it to be displayed, use `gone`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

instead.

`INVISIBLE` will do the equivalent of making your view 100% transparent, but `GONE` will make your view disappear, and all the other views in the layout will recalculate their positions as if your view never existed.

Comment: I tried that earlier, didn't work, Now it started working

Answer (score 3):

From [Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)

GONE :- This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

INVISIBLE :- This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

This was the reason why you were able to see the spaces in it. You could directly use setVisibility(View.GONE) for

Answer (score 2):

you can hide the card view from the java class. 
In order to do that get the 2 ids of each card view and do as follows

```
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;

CardView card_view, cv_ad;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        card_view = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        cv_ad = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cv_ad);
        card_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cv_ad.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```